# java.lang.NullPointerException when running program

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, constructor, paint

I have 4 classes. One is the abstract entity class, one is a ball class, one is the main class and the other is the screen class.

The ball class extends the entity class and has 5 variables.

The screen function has a paint method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    ball.paint(g);
}
```

And of course, to use ball.paint need to make an object for it. So, I make ball object:

```
Ball ball;
```

And then add this in the screen constructor, since I need to (Ball has a constructor which takes 5 variables):

```
public Screen(){
    ball = new Ball(ball.getWeight(), ball.getWidth(), ball.getHeight(), ball.getX(), ball.getX());
}
```

This comes up with no errors, but when I run the program, I get this error in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at h3x.engine.gfx.Screen.<init>(Screen.java:18)
at h3x.engine.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

Line 16 of the main class is this:

```
frame.add(new Screen());
```

...and line 18 of the screen class is this:

```
ball = new Ball(ball.getWeight(), ball.getWidth(), ball.getHeight(), ball.getX(), ball.getX());
```

So my question is, why is this happening, and how can I fix it. I can put in the whole code in the classes if it is needed.

Thanks!

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, before that to put all Ball to the array, inside paintComponent to pick up Balls from array, invoked from Swing Timer, otheriwse every answers here could be shorts to the dark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call:

```
ball = new Ball(ball.getXxx()....)
```

which means you expect to retrieve values from the instance you initialize. And before initialization is complete, it is null. Hence the NPE (short for `NullPointerException`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, how I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: You need to pass values to the constructor (for weight, width etc). Real values ;) If you have default values, just create an empty constructor and do `new Ball()`. That will fix at least the `ball` initialization. After that...

Comment: So, how I can prevent this from happening?  == by removing ball.paint(g);, re_read my commnent, again these answers are based on your vague question

Answer (score 3):

Your line

```
Ball ball;
```

Isn't actually making a new Ball object, so the reference `ball` is set to `null`.  When you try to retrieve the `ball` members in the constructor, it's throwing the `NullPointerException`.  Using the members of an object instance in its own constructor is kind of suspect in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this line:

```
ball = new Ball(ball.getWeight(), ball.getWidth(), ball.getHeight(), ball.getX(), ball.getX());
```

You're trying to assign values to `ball` that don't exist yet. Pass in some real values instead:

```
ball = new Ball(5, 4, 2, 7, 7);
```